# Merging PDFs automatically with pdftk

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, merge, pdftk

I have the following situation:

I have 5 different folders containing PDF files.

**Folder 1** contains one PDF - the front page, for example `Front Page.pdf`.
This should be the front page for each new generated PDF file.

**Folder 2** contains different named PDF files, each beginning with **1_***FileName*, for example `1_abcd_123.pdf`, `1_ghi_675.pdf`. Number of characters is not the same, the only common thing is that they all start with `1_`.
This should be page 2.

**Folder 3** contains the same number of PDF files like **Folder 2**. The PDF files are named exactly the same as in **Folder 2** except they start with `2_`.

**Folder 4** contains the same number of PDF files like **Folder 2** and **Folder 3**. The PDF files are named exactly the same as in **Folder 2** and **Folder 3** except they all start with `3_`.

**Folder 5** contains one PDF, for example `LastPage.pdf`.
This should be the last page in each generated PDF.

Now I want to merge front page and the 3 matching PDF files from the folders 2, 3, 4 and last page into one PDF.

I started to research online and found that this should be done with a PDF merger like `pdftk` in a batch process.

The problem in this example [FOR loop group each iteration with same prefix in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823742/for-loop-group-each-iteration-with-same-prefix-in-one-line) comes close to mine. But the difference is that I have different folders and that the process should look for matching data in the end of the name and not in the beginning.

Anyone can help?

I have no experience in this field at all but tried to get into this topic as best as I could.

Answer (score 0):

The demo batch code below demonstrates how to

- run a command/executable/script for each file found in **Folder 2** with file name, file extension and with full path without double quotes assigned to loop variable `#`,
- with splitting up the name of the found file without path - `%%~nx#` (file name and file extension) - into two parts because of `tokens=1*` based on first underscore because of `delims=_` in name of file whereby

  - the first part always being just `1` is assigned to loop variable `I` which is not further used and
  - everything after first underscore being assigned to loop variable `J` which is the next character after `I` in ASCII table and
- process the command with 6 full file names whereby the last full file name is the new file to produce from the other 5 file names.

Demo code:

```
@echo off
set "SourceFolder=C:\Temp"
for %%# in ("%SourceFolder%\Folder 2\*") do (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%I in ("%%~nx#") do (
        echo "%SourceFolder%\Folder 1\Front Page.pdf" "%%#" "%SourceFolder%\Folder 3\2_%%J" "%SourceFolder%\Folder 4\3_%%J" "%SourceFolder%\Folder 5\LastPage.pdf" "%SourceFolder%\%%J"
    )
)
set "SourceFolder="
```

The output for the two files `1_abcd_123.pdf` and `1_ghi_675.pdf` in **Folder 2** in `C:\Temp` is:

```
"C:\Temp\Folder 1\Front Page.pdf" "C:\Temp\Folder 2\1_abcd_123.pdf" "C:\Temp\Folder 3\2_abcd_123.pdf" "C:\Temp\Folder 4\3_abcd_123.pdf" "C:\Temp\Folder 5\LastPage.pdf" "C:\Temp\abcd_123.pdf"
"C:\Temp\Folder 1\Front Page.pdf" "C:\Temp\Folder 2\1_ghi_675.pdf" "C:\Temp\Folder 3\2_ghi_675.pdf" "C:\Temp\Folder 4\3_ghi_675.pdf" "C:\Temp\Folder 5\LastPage.pdf" "C:\Temp\ghi_675.pdf"
```

I don't have *PDFTK* downloaded, installed and read the documentation. So what is finally needed instead of command **ECHO** to merge the 5 input PDF files together to a new output PDF file must be found out by yourself.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`

Comment: sorry for not responding sooner, I will look into this these days. Thanks!